# How to compare two columns from dataframe and return corresponding record if match found?

Tags: python, dataframe, string-comparison

I want to match the strings from 2 dataframes and if match found the return the corresponding results. So my first dataframe contains:

```
Name
abc
pqr
xyz
```

And second dataframe contains

```
Id Name
1 abc
2 lmn
3 pqr
4 qwe
```

I want to return ID by comparing (string) Name columns. And additionally, how to achieve the same, if Name from abc will get compared with entire names from dataframe 2.

The code as follows which I was trying after combing 2 dataframes:
This is a function which will compare the strings and return difference.

```
def bit_func(x):
    dmp = diff_match_patch()
    patches = dmp.patch_make(x.Name1, x.Name2)
    diff = dmp.patch_toText(patches)
    return diff
```

And I have tried to get difference but the code is not working. And I also want corresponding ID for the name how to return the same?

```
df['diff'] = df.apply(bit_func, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use pandas [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) functionality to show the matches between the DataFrames and the Ids associated with them:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['abc', 'pqr', 'xyz']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['abc', 'lmn', 'pqr', 'qwe'], 'Id': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

print(df1.merge(df2))
```

Output is:

```
Name  Id
0  abc   1
1  pqr   3
```

To get the difference between the two use the following:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True).query('_merge != "both"').drop('_merge', 1)
```

Which outputs:

```
  Name   Id
2  xyz  NaN
3  lmn  2.0
4  qwe  4.0
```

**Reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) for all merge queries**

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not which I want. I am using function so how to achieve the same by passing it to the function is concern. I have updated the code.

Comment: So you want to return the difference between both dataframes?